# Dynamic Programming for Dice probability in a Role Playing Pen & Paper game

Tags: python, algorithm

The Dark Eye is a popular fantasy role-playing game, the German equivalent of Dungeons and Dragons. In this system a character has a number of attributes and talents. Each talent has several attributes associated with it, and to make a talent check the player rolls a d20 (a 20-sided die) for each associated attribute. Each time a roll result exceeds the attribute score, the difference between roll and attribute is added up. If this difference total (the excess ) is greater than the talent value, the check fails.

**Your first task for this tutorial is to write a function that takes as input a list of attribute scores associated with a talent as well as the talent ranks, and returns the probability that the test succeeds. Your algorithm must work efficiently for lists of arbitrary length.**

Hint: First write a function that computes the probability distribution for the excess. This can be done efficiently using dynamic programming.

---

What does this mean? I solved the knapsack problem without any major issues (both 0/1 and unbounded), but I have no idea what to do with this?

The smallest problem to solve first would be rank 1 with a single attribute of say 12 (using the example above) - the probability of passing would be 12/20 right? then rank 2 would be 13/20 then rank 3 would be 14/20?

Am I on the right track? I feel like I might be misunderstanding the actual game rules.

Comment: Imagine there is only 1 attribute. What is the probability for the excess to be 0? 1? 2? 3? …
Now imagine there is a second attribute. Given the probabilities for the first attribute, what is the probability for the excess after the two tests to be 0? 1? 2? 3? …

Comment: The probability of passing for one attribute (12) and a rank of 1 is 13/20: For a dice roll of 13, the excess is 1; it has to be counted, too.

Comment: I understand the logic, but not how to find the probability with the dynamic programming. I can do the first row (ie, rank 1 is 13/20, rank 2 is 14/20 up to rank 7 which is 19/20), but when I add another die, how do I calculate it. I did it on a spreadsheet and found that at rank 7, the probability for two attributes at skill levels 12 and 13 is 88% chance of passing, but I can't find any formula for the dynamic programming grid to solve each step.

Comment: >The probability of passing for one attribute (12) and a rank of 1 is 13/20: For a dice roll of 13, the excess is 1; it has to be counted, too.

Do you mean I need to count the excess, so keep a tuple in that location with the probability and the excess? I may have misunderstood first time.

Comment: I would create a map for a single attribute that maps excesses to their probability e.g. `p = {0: 12, 1: 1, ..., 8: 1}`. Then use a similar map to accumulate these probabilites for all attributes. At the end you sum the probabilites of map entries that are less or equal than the rank and divide by the total number of possible dice rolls. Note that the rank only comes into play in the last step. (And you can always check your algorithm against a brute force solution.)

Comment: I don't wanna do it for you, but I think you need to focus on that to find your recurrence relation. "Given the probabilities for the first attribute, what is the probability for the excess after the two tests to be 0? 1? 2? 3? …"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I've been trying to figure out some kind of relation in excel, using a spreadsheet. I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Do not calculate probabilities. Calculate the "number of ways it can happen" (already forgot what its called, been a long time), and once you got all of it, divide it by the total number of possible rolls (20^n).

Answer (score 1):

A single roll against an attribute of value k is a random variable, which takes the values 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 20-k with probabilities k/20, 1/20, 1/20, ...

You can represent this as an array of size 21-k, with the probabilities as values in the array.

If you have two (independent) random variables, X1 and X2, then the random variable expressing their sum is:

```
P(X1+X2=n) = sum(i=0 to n)P(X1=i)*P(X2=n-i)
```

You can use this iteratively to compute the distribution of the sum of all your attribute rolls. Then you can find the probability of making the saving roll by summing the probabilities in the final distribution up to the value S (the saving roll value).

One neat optimisation you can make is to not store any probabilities above the value S since they're never used. This just means making limiting the size of your arrays to S+1 and doing bounds checking.

Putting all that together gives this code. The `multiply` function has complexity O(len(a1)*len(a2)) but because a1 is always of length S+1 and a2 has length at most 21, it has complexity O(S). Overall, this gives this code the complexity O(nS) where n is the number of attributes you have. I've included some test run code against attributes [5, 10].

```
def attribute_dist(k):
    return [k/20.0] + [1/20.0] * (20-k)

def multiply(a1, a2):
    result = [0] * len(a1)
    for n in xrange(len(a1)):
        for i in xrange(len(a2)):
            if 0 <= n - i < len(a1):
                result[n] += a1[n-i] * a2[i]
    return result

def saving_throw_probability(attributes, S):
    d = [1.0] + [0] * S
    for a in attributes:
        d = multiply(d, attribute_dist(a))
    return sum(d)

for i in xrange(30):
    print i, saving_throw_probability([5, 10], i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat bit of mathematics involving probability and polynomials. For example, rolling a d6 could be represented by the polynomial

```
x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6
-------------------------------
               6                ,
```

since rolling a 1 has probability 1/6 (the x/6 term), rolling a 2 has probability 1/6 (the x^2/6 term), etc. Rolling a d20 and counting the excess over 13 would be

```
13 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7
------------------------------------------
                    20                     .
```

The point of this representation is that, if Y is a random variable with polynomial p(x), and Z is a random variable with polynomial q(x), then the polynomial of Y + Z is the product p(x) q(x). For example, multiplying the d6 polynomial by itself, we get the 2d6 polynomial,

```
x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^5 + 5 x^6 + 6 x^7 + 5 x^8 + 4 x^9 + 3 x^10 + 2 x^11 + x^12
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         36                                          ,
```

which should be recognizable as the right distribution.

The brute force algorithm here corresponds to a generalized version of the firsts-outers-inners-lasts (FOIL) rule for multiplying two linear polynomials, where, for each possible choice of one term per polynomial factor, we add the product to the final sum. This is inefficient because, e.g., if we're trying to compute the heads distribution of n coins by examining ((1 + x)/2)^n, we'll end up summing 2^n terms.

The dynamic programming algorithm being alluded to is the more reasonable approach of computing partial products. For example, we compute ((1 + x)/2)^2 = (1 + 2 x + x^2)/4, then (1 + 2 x + x^2)/4 (1 + x)/2 = (1 + 3 x + 3 x^2 + 1)/8, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is: how many ways can you roll with attributes 12, 13 and 12 and a talent of 7. Lets assume you know the outcome of the first dice, lets say its 11. Then the problem is reduced to how many ways can you roll with attributes 13 and 12 and with a talent of 7. Now try it with a different first roll, lets say you rolled 14 for the first time. You are over by 2, so the problem now is how many ways can you roll with attributes 13 and 12 and with a talent of 5. Now try with a first roll of 20. The question now is how many ways can you roll with attributes 13 and 12 and with a talent of -1 (in the last case its obviously 0).